# Permanently save iOS backups

Tags: macos, itunes, ios, backup

Whenever I connect my iPad to my mac itunes backs up it's current state. This is great and I want to keep it this way. Though it overrides the previous backup, which is ok most of the time, but now I want to keep my current state, permanently.
So is there a way to select the current backup and keep it saved permanently, without it being overridden next backup?

By extension, is it also possible to keep iOS 6.1.2 saved somewhere (even after 6.1.3 is released), so I can try out 6.1.3 but can then always go back to 6.1.2 for jailbreaking? I was thinking of just restoring my iPad to 6.1.2, then back it up, and then save that backup, but perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: I don't know for Mac but at least on Windows, all the files are saved in C:\ProgramData\Apple and %userprofile%\AppData\Local. Equivalent locations would be there for OS X too

Comment: Are you wanting to save the contents, or the iOS version?

Comment: Both, I though a backup backed up everything (settings, apps, iOS.)

Comment: no the backup only contains, contacts settings, pics not os related stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~user/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup

Just copy it :)

if you want the os too

[iOS Firmwares](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that does not include the iOS.

Comment: it never does? the os is seperate!

Comment: Although iTunes does store the user data of the OS there, 'backing up' the iOS firmware files is fruitless

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, iTunes will save iOS backups to `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup`
On PC, they're in in `%appdata%\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup`

When iTunes creates these backups, it will only store your user files, not a copy of the OS as well. This doesn't make sense because you can only ever restore the latest version of iOS on a device. Rolling back to a previous version is just not possible.

Comment: Note: Downgrading can be possible in some circumstances, but only if you have previously jailbroken your phone and have saved you 'SHSH blobs. Check out http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/02/02/how-to-save-shsh-blobs-for-ios-6-1/ for more details

Answer (score 0):

Configure Time Machine and ensure it's backing up the folder where iTunes stores the iOS backups.

Depending on your needs, you could also archive a snapshot of that folder as desired and store it somewhere that it can't be deleted, since Time Machine could erase older backups if the space runs low on the destination.